# WPF charting, how to change label position?

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts, wpftoolkit

I have a chart of WPF Column series, the labels in the chart are getting overlapped if there are lot of datapoints. How can I make them vertical? The image explains better.

[image]

Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9371950/2619912

Comment: Track the label on the side .